# How can I convert/populate a List<JsTreeModel> with a select statement from my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, jstree

I'm following along with this tutorial (http://dotnetqueries.com/Article/62/implementing-jstree-in-asp-net-mvc-with-json-data), and I have everything up and working correctly. The only change I am trying to make now is to populate

```
var nodes = new List<JsTreeModel>
```

with data from my database, rather than hard-coded values. For reference, JsTreeModel looks as such:

```
public class JsTreeModel
 {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
 }
```

I was able to figure out how to do the select list from the database:

```
var jslist = db.My_Table.Select(x => new {id = x.id, parent = x.parent_code, text = x.Name}).ToList();
```

The issue is that this is a list for My_Table types, not a JsTreeModel. How can I store my select results into a JsTreeModel list type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
List<JsTreeModel> jslist = db.My_Table.Select(x => new JsTreeModel {
        id = x.id.ToString(), 
          parent = x.parent_code, 
          text = x.Name
          }).ToList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like a few people did not understand my question, have voted my question down, and have marked it to be closed. Given how this issue is now resolved, I will go ahead and delete this post. Thanks again!